# Request to allow "Download as PGN" feature

Tags: feature-request, pgn-viewer

Quite a lot of chess questions involve analyzing a certain position or game posted by the user asking the question. For example -

[Did Aronian make a mistake in the opening against Anand in round 1 of the FIDE Candidates 2014?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5015/did-aronian-make-a-mistake-in-the-opening-against-anand-in-round-1-of-the-fide-c/5016#5016)

It would be useful if there is a way to download the game provided by the user as a PGN file for quick analysis with an engine (screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: While it doesn't exactly download to a PGN file, there is a "Copy Game" option available from the down-arrow appearing at the top right of the PGN viewer. The game can then be pasted into a new/existing PGN file directly.

Comment: Yes its a nice addition to a CHESS question and answer site to have PGN files downloadable.

Comment: @EdDean post your comment as an answer? It seems to be the best answer so far, apart from copy pasting by hand or clicking "edit" and copy-pasting from there...

Answer (score 3):

While it doesn't exactly download to a PGN file, there is a "Copy Game" option available from the down-arrow appearing at the top right of the PGN viewer. The game can then be pasted into a new/existing PGN file directly.

Comment: +1 That's useful, but a bit less user friendly.